# How to make this search in a new thread

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I have search as you type functionality although it searches very fast and I can't notice it even with no multithreading I still want to know how would I use multithreading on this

```
search.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observableValue, String s, String s2) {
                manager.searchString(s2);
                listView.getItems().setAll(manager.getList());
            }
        });
```

So basically there is a `TextField` that when its text is changed I go and call a search method in object `manager` which puts its search result in an array when it finishes.

Then the `ListView` should update its data to this new array when it finishes.

How can I make the search on one thread and when it finishes it update the list data?!

I believe I can't just call the list function from other thread because GUI stuff should be called from only one thread.

Comment: For Swing, there is a [good documentation about concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/). For JavaFX, there seems to be a [similar document](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm), haven't read it though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this efficiently in a different thread is not as simple as it sounds.

You don't want to create and execute a new thread every time a key is pressed because:

1. There is system overhead for thread creation which would make that an extremely intensive process
2. There's no guarantee that the threads will execute and complete in the order they are created, so you may get an earlier thread finishing *after* a subsequent one and consequentially updating the list with invalid entries.

You could use a single-thread executor service (which keeps one thread alive and uses it to execute Runnables passed into it in order), which would be more efficient, but you'd need to remember to shut it down when your text field is destroyed (if you do ever destroy your text field).  Something along these lines:

```
// first of all, at the class level (assuming listView and manager are both class-level variables, preferably final ones, too):

// An INNER class implementing Runnable which will carry out the searching
private class Searcher implements Runnable {
    private volatile boolean cancelled = false;
    private final String searchTerm;
    Searcher(String searchTerm) {
        this.searchTerm = searchTerm; 
    }

    public void cancel() {
       cancelled = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
       // remember that there's no guarantee that this will execute before the NEXT keypress, so we add a check to ensure that we still want to perform the search when it gets executed:
       if (!cancelled) {
           manager.searchString(searchTerm);
           Platform.runLater(listViewUpdater); // listViewUpdater is defined below
       }
    }
}

// a Runnable to actually update the GUI after a seach has been performed
private Runnable listViewUpdater = new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        listView.getItems().setAll(manager.getList());
    }
}

private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
private Searcher lastSearcher = null;

// ... then, in the method which sets up the GUI
search.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observableValue, String s, String s2) {
            if (lastSearcher != null) {
                lastSearcher.cancel(); // prevents lastSearcher from running if it hasn't done so already
            }
            lastSearcher = new Searcher(s2);
            executor.submit(lastSearcher);
        }
    });
```

The downside is you are creating a new object every time the value changes, but that isn't nearly as bad as creating a new Thread every time.

Comment: can I add some code checking in the searchString method to stop search when it is cancelled??

Comment: Yes, if you change the signature of searchString to take the Searcher instance as a second parameter, pass in the instance of Searcher which calls the method, and add an isCancelled() method inside the Searcher class then the searchString method can periodically check the isCancelled() method of the Searcher which called it.